# localRotation is not rotating around the cube center

Tags: android, sceneform

Sceneform 1.15 on Android

I want to make that the cube renderable is rotating around the own centar.

```
val anchorNode = AnchorNode().apply {
                setParent(scene)
                worldPosition = Vector3(2f, 3f, 0f)
            }

            scene.addChild(anchorNode)

            dieNode = Node().apply {
                setParent(anchorNode)
                localRotation = Quaternion.eulerAngles(Vector3(10f,20f,60f))
                name = "die"
                renderable = it
            }
```

I made an animator that is supposed to only rotate the cube around its own center.

```
private fun roll() {
    val anim = createAnimator()
    val node = scene.findByName("die")!!
    anim.target = node
    anim.setDuration(9000)
    anim.start()
}

private fun createAnimator() : ObjectAnimator {
    val o1 = Quaternion.eulerAngles(Vector3(-90f,180f,90f))
    val animator = ObjectAnimator()
    animator.setObjectValues(o1)
    animator.setPropertyName("localRotation")
    animator.setEvaluator(QuaternionEvaluator())
    animator.setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator())
    animator.setAutoCancel(true)
    return animator
}
```

But, it happens that while cube is rotating, it is also moved which is not desired behavior.

Screenshots where one of the symetrically placed die in world should be only rotated:
[image: symetrically placed]
[image: one cube rotated]

Comment: What do you mean by "The cube center is moved while animating rotation"?

Specifying your question will be a help to an appropriate answer.

Comment: I updated answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The position is not centred for the Cube object. If it is off the centre with respect to the parent object, it will rotate around (0,0,0), if it lies off this axis - the object will move in a circle, not rotate.